# How to define a Kerr-Schild metric in xAct?

Tags: physics, tensors, xact

A Kerr-Schild can be expressed as $g_{ab}=\eta_{ab}+\phi k_a k_b$, where $\eta_{ab}$ is Minkowski metric, $\phi$ is a scalar function and $k_a$ is a (co)vector field which is null and geodetic with respect to both the Minkowski and full metric, i.e.
$g_{ab}k^ak^b=\eta_{ab}k^ak^b=0$ and $k^a\nabla_ak^b=0$. In order to define a Kerr-Schild metric in xAct, I guess I should define two metrics, a scalar function, a null and geodetic vector first. But I don't know how to construct Minkowski metric, null and geodetic vector. And I don't know how to establish a connection between $g_{ab}$ and $\eta_{ab}$.

In addition, after define a Ker-Schild metric, I want to do some abstract geometric calculations about this metric, such as using $\phi$ and $k_a$ to represent Ricci tensor or Riemann tensor.

Comment: What do you ultimately want to do with this metric?  Are you looking to do this in some kind of coordinate basis (using xCoba), treating $\phi$ and $k_\mu$ as functions of the Minkowski coordinates?  Or are you looking to do more abstract geometric calculations?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I  am looking to do more abstract geometric calculations, such as using the scalar function, null and geodetic vector to represent Ricci tensor or Riemann tensor.